# angular-oauth2-oidc angular 17 standalone

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

I am using angular 17 standalone. I installed the angular-oauth2-oidc library. It turns out that he doesn't get the token. I have the same angular application in an older version with NgModule and it works fine. Do you know a way to solve the problem? It is also possible to change the library to one that will work with Angular Standalone

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {
        this.configureOAuth();
    }
    private configureOAuth(): void {
        const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
            issuer: 'url',
            redirectUri: window.location.origin,
            responseType: 'code',
            requireHttps: false,
            clientId: 'm0063',
            scope: 'openid profile email offline_access roles',
        };
        this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
        //this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin();
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {}

    login() {
        this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin().then(x => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.oauthService.initCodeFlow();
            });
        });
    }

    logout() {
        this.oauthService.logOut({ customParameters: true, client_id: 'm0063' });
    }
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [
        provideAnimations(),
        provideHttpClient(),
        provideRouter(
            appRoutes,
            withPreloading(PreloadAllModules),
            withInMemoryScrolling({ scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' }),
            withViewTransitions()
        ),
        importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
        provideOAuthClient( {
            resourceServer: {
                allowedUrls: ['localhost:4200', 'url:8080'],
                sendAccessToken: true
          }
        }
        ),
        provideUrl(),
}
```

error:`your text`
Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

I trying do new module and implement config as in For.root in ngModule, but it is not working still.

Comment: Same here, in one specific app the oidc 17 doest work with the angular 17.

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular 17, angular-oauth2-oidc and keycloak.

This approach worked for me:

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {AuthConfig, OAuthService} from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
    import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
    import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class AuthService {
      constructor(private oauthService: OAuthService) {}

      authConfig: AuthConfig = {
        responseType: 'code',
        scope: 'openid profile email',
        redirectUri: window.location.origin,
        oidc: true,
        requestAccessToken: true,
        showDebugInformation: true,
        strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
        useSilentRefresh: true,
        issuer: `${environment.KEYCLOAK_URL}realms/${environment.KEYCLOAK_REALM}`,
        clientId: environment.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
      };

      initAuth() {
        this.oauthService.configure(this.authConfig);
        this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
        this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
      }

      login() {
        this.initAuth();
        this.oauthService.initCodeFlow();
      }

      logout() {
        this.oauthService.logOut();
      }

      isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
        return of(this.oauthService.hasValidIdToken());
      }

      getAccessToken(): string {
        const accessToken = this.oauthService.getAccessToken();
        return accessToken;
      }
    }
```

I provided the oAuth2Lib in my Applicationconfig like this:

```
    export const coreConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
      providers: [
         provideOAuthClient()
      ]
    }
```

You may also have to provide the "AuthService" in your standalone app.component.ts and call "initAuth()" within your constructor. I have not found a better solution yet.

```
export class CoreComponent {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
  ) {
    this.authService.initAuth();
  }
}
```